# Gradle failed - unable to find method com.google.common.io.CharSource.readLines

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error when trying to change the java version in android studio from jdk1.8 to jdk 1.7.

**Error:**

```
  Error:Unable to find method com.google.common.io.CharSource.readLines'(Lcom/google/common/io/LineProcessor;)Ljava/lang/Object;'.
  Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
```

**Gradle Error**

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.something"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

**backend:**

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
  appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
  compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
  compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
}

appengine {
  downloadSdk = true
  appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
  }
  endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Overloaded readLines(LineProcessor processor)** function was added in ***guava-16.0.1.jar*** or +. But **JAVA 1.8.0.25 uses *guava-14.0.1.jar***. So we need to **update JAVA to 1.8.0.66**(or less, but should update guava jar).